# Dynamic Navigation with Condition to check slug

Tags: conditional, navigation, forloop, entry-slug

I'm trying to achieve one pretty simple thing, but putting it into my dynamic nav is making it a little difficult. I want to have a little number of the total amount of entries in my channel "listings" and keep it on one of the links "Our Properties".

[image: What the main Nav has to look like]

I currently have this code that is displaying the total amount of entries

```
{% set totalListings = craft.entries.section('listings').total() %}
{{ totalListings }}
```

How can I make this work: {% if link == "properties" single entry %} {{ totalListings}} {% endif %}

```
{% set menu = craft.entries.section('navigation') %}
<ul> 
    {% nav link in menu.all %}
        <li {% if craft.app.request.absoluteUrl == link.addentry[0].url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
           <a href="{{ link.addentry[0].url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work! I don't know why I made it so complicated in my head, but I ended up using the link id to match with the properties link.

```
{% nav link in menu.all %}
    <li {% if craft.app.request.absoluteUrl == link.addentry[0].url %} class="active"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ link.addentry[0].url }}">{{ link.title }}{% if link.id == 15 %}<span class="exposant">{% set totalListings = craft.entries.section('listings').total() %}{{ totalListings }}</span>{% endif %}</a>
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```

If someone can show me how to get it by slug that would be awesome! Thanks & hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: What do you mean with "get it by slug"? You can check the `link.uri` attribute for singles or the much better approach `entry.getType.handle`